# Need a CSL style that uses the month field in Bibtex

Tags: citations, bibtex

I do a lot of academic writing where I need to cite magazine and newspaper articles.  My workflow is to write in Markdown / Org-mode and then export to docx using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org).  So I use the citation facility provided by `pandoc-citeproc` to generate my bibliography from an old BibTex file that I've been using for many years.

I know that standard BibTex doesn't support newspaper articles directly, so for years I've been using the kludge [mentioned here](http://texblog.org/2007/08/09/how-to-use-a-bibtex-file/#comment-4419) and adding the day to the month field.  This has worked fine for several years.  But over the last several months I've been running into problems - the standard default csl format for `pandoc-citeproc` drops the month field entirely when producing the bibliography.  The same happens with `apa.csl`, `chicago-author-date.csl`, and several other styles I've tried from the [CSL Library](http://citationstyles.org).

I don't want to manually rewrite the hundreds of entries in my BibTex file.  Is there a CSL file that will include the month information in the bibliography entries?  Is there another way to get that information easily?

Comment: Perhaps better on a Software Question stack...

Comment: @SolarMike - probably true. Any suggestions on which one though? Super User?

Comment: Check, you might find one with similar questions or even relevant tags.

Comment: Try https://tex.stackexchange.com/